# Is the equation of an aldehyde to a carboxylic acid in alkaline conditions correct?

Tags: organic-chemistry

The equation is:

$$\ce{RCHO +2OH- -> RCOOH + 2e- + H2O}$$

If it isn't correct, then please explain.

Comment: What will happen to a carboxylic acid in the presence of hydroxide?

Comment: @bon I was trying to work out the half equation of it and combine it with the half equation of Cu2+ to copper oxide(1).

Comment: Ok but what will happen to the acid in the presence of hydroxide?

Comment: @bon Become water?

Comment: @bon So I started off with RCHO + H2O = RCOOH + 2H+  +  e- .  Then I added hydroxide ions onto both sides and then simplified the water molecules.

Comment: Yes but you have still missed something. Hydroxide is a strong base so what will happen when you add it to the carboxylic acid.

Comment: @bon  I think I understand now. So you get a carboxylate ion (RCOO-). and , therefore the half-equation would be : RCHO +3OH- = RCOO- +2H2O +2e-. Is that correct, Also, if I wanted to retain the RCOOH, what would I also have to do.

Comment: Protonate the carboxylate by flooding the reaction mixture with acid after the oxidation has finished.

Comment: What is it supposed to be? Half of Cannizzaro reaction? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost correct. The only thing you have missed is that hydroxide is a strong base, so when you have a carboxylic acid in a reaction mixture with hydroxide it will be deprotonated. Therefore the overall half equation would be: $$\ce{RCHO + 3OH- -> RCOO- + 2H2O + 2e-}$$

If you want to get the carboyxlic acid you would have to flood the reaction mixture with acid after the oxidation has finished, in order to protonate the carboxylate anion.